# Front end ajax user login session issue

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, session, frontend

I am having an issue where the ajax login form allows me to login, sort of. If I set the redirect to the homepage after login it sends me to the homepage and gives me the admin bar at the top. However if I try to then go to the admin dashboard it asks me to login again with the normal wordpress login.

How can solve this issue? My codes:

in page-login.php template:

```
<form id="login" class="ajax-auth" action="login" method="post">
    <p class="status"></p>  
    <?php wp_nonce_field('ajax-login-nonce', 'security'); ?>  
    <div class="form-group">
        <input id="username" placeholder="<?php _e('Username','my-theme'); ?>" type="text" class="required form-control" name="username">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input id="password" placeholder="<?php _e('Password','my-theme'); ?>" type="password" class="required form-control" name="password">
    </div>
    <input class="btn btn-block btn-md btn-info" type="submit" value="<?php _e('Login','my-theme'); ?>">
</form>
```

in functions.php:

```
function ajax_auth_init(){  
  global $theme_options;
  $userProfilePage=$theme_options['opt-user-select'];

  wp_register_script('ajax-auth-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/ajax-logreg-script.js', array('jquery') ); 
  wp_enqueue_script('ajax-auth-script');

  wp_localize_script( 'ajax-auth-script', 'ajax_auth_object', array( 
    'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
    'redirecturl' => get_page_link($userProfilePage),
    'loadingmessage' => __('Please wait...','my-theme')
  ));

  // Enable the user with no privileges to run ajax_login() in AJAX
  add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_ajaxlogin', 'ajax_login' );
}
// Execute the action only if the user isn't logged in
if (!is_user_logged_in()) {
    add_action('init', 'ajax_auth_init');
}
function ajax_login(){

  // First check the nonce, if it fails the function will break
  check_ajax_referer( 'ajax-login-nonce', 'security' );

    // Nonce is checked, get the POST data and sign user on
    // Call auth_user_login
  auth_user_login($_POST['username'], $_POST['password'], __('Login','my-theme')); 

  die();
}
function auth_user_login($user_login, $password, $login){
  $info = array();
  $info['user_login'] = $user_login;
  $info['user_password'] = $password;
  $info['remember'] = true;

  $user_signon = wp_signon( $info, false );
    if ( is_wp_error($user_signon) ){
    echo json_encode(array('loggedin'=>false, 'message'=>__('Wrong password or username.','my-theme')));
    } else {
    wp_set_current_user($user_signon->ID); 
        echo json_encode(array('loggedin'=>true, 'message'=> $login.__(' successful, redirecting...','my-theme')));
    }

  die();
}
```

and ajax-logreg-script.js file:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

    // Perform AJAX login/register on form submit
    $('form#login, form#register').on('submit', function (e) {
        if (!$(this).valid()) return false;
        $('p.status', this).show().text(ajax_auth_object.loadingmessage);
        action = 'ajaxlogin';
        username =  $('form#login #username').val();
        password = $('form#login #password').val();
        email = '';
        security = $('form#login #security').val(); 
        ctrl = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            url: ajax_auth_object.ajaxurl,
            data: {
                'action': action,
                'username': username,
                'password': password,
                'email': email,
                'security': security,
            },
            success: function (data) {
                $('p.status', ctrl).text(data.message);
                if (data.loggedin == true)
                  document.location.href = ajax_auth_object.redirecturl;
                else if (ctrl == 'register')
                  grecaptcha.reset();
            }
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    $(".logreg-page form#login").validate({
        ignore: ".ignore",
       rules: {
         username: {
            required: true,
          },
          password: {
            required: true,
          },
       },
       messages: {
          username: "Please enter an username.",
          password: "Please enter your password.",
        },
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

If your site with SSL, Set the second parameter of wp_signon function to true.

```
$user_signon = wp_signon( $info, true);
```

Comment: I think this is working, thank you. However, the admin bar does not appear before refresh the page. How can I do cache cleaning when logged in? How to check site using SSL? and what is the difference between true or false?

Comment: Admin bar content printed in the footer when user logged-in and need page refresh. for check site with SSL using is_ssl() function. But you don't need use this function just set true.

Comment: The problem is solved if I set the sucre cookie parameter in wp_signon to ''. I checked through Wordpress Codex, this is the default parameter. No "true" or "false". https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_signon/

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
function auth_user_login($user_login, $password, $login){
  $info = array();
  $info['user_login'] = $user_login;
  $info['user_password'] = $password;
  $info['remember'] = true;

  $user_signon = wp_signon( $info, false );
    if ( is_wp_error($user_signon) ){
    echo json_encode(array('loggedin'=>false, 'message'=>__('Wrong password or username.','my-theme')));
    } else {   
    $userID = $user_signon->ID;
    wp_set_current_user( $userID, $user_login );
    wp_set_auth_cookie( $userID, true, false );
    echo json_encode(array('loggedin'=>true, 'message'=> $login.__(' successful, redirecting...','my-theme')));
    }

  die();
}
```

Comment: Sorry this doesn't work :( Logging in but the default Wordpress login screen comes when I want to go to the dashboard.

Comment: you are logged in as user or admin?

Comment: admin. I don't allow users to access the admin panel. There is an user account page at the front end.

Comment: your site is SSL?

Comment: Yes working in local. But my site is live :) The problem is solved if I set the sucre cookie parameter in wp_signon to ''. I checked through Wordpress Codex, this is the default parameter. No "true" or "false". There's only one problem. The user was redirected to the homepage after login. However, the admin bar does not appear because it is cached. It appears when I refresh the page. How can I automatically do the refresh cache when logged in?